# Texture Assistance Needed

Tags: texturing

[image]I am trying to import an .obj, however when I load the model, it is grey. All tutorials I found online are for older versions of blender. I was wondering if anyone could help me out real quick. Apologies, as I have just downloaded blender today and am learning. Thanks

Comment: This is a question and answer site. You have not asked any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Normally all objects are grey when imported, you have to add a material first, then the textures in the SHADER EDITOR, and switch to the rendered view, right now you are in object view which is white for all objects. For the shading in the shader editor Shift + A-->Texture-->Image Texture, which will add a texture, open the file of your texture in browse and plug the colour to base colour and alpha value to alpha in the Principled BSDF. Also please reply if only rotation or parts of the texture are on the object(usually they are not). This method is really old and basic so that's why you can't find tutorials in the new versions.[image]