# How do I add textures and materials to an .FBX model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I downloaded a model [here](https://p3dm.ru/files/characters/13561-detroit-become-human-connor.html). When I import the mesh as .FBX into Blender, it loads as a completely grey model. I am new to Blender and have no idea where to begin. It is composed of numerous "submeshes".

The materials come in one folder as .tbmat. The textures are in another folder as .jpg, .png, and .tga.

The mesh also comes as an .OBJ, and loads into Blender as completely grey too.

I want to apply the textures and materials so that the end result is the same as what's pictured on the webpage.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: here is the same question, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169862/texture-assistance-needed/169877#169877

Comment: Hello :). Models from *P3dm.ru* come without an .mtl file, which is used to automatically assign textures to the model. Either do it manually or try other sites (like *turbosquid.com*).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks everyone, but the issue is that I don't know how to apply the textures and materials. I literally don't know where to begin with it. The questions that have been linked give answers where it's expected that people know how to apply textures and materials. Hence the reason why I ask how to apply them. One of the linked questions gives some instructions, but the model I linked has numerous submeshes and works differently.